# Proving a simple recurrence relation via induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

There is a recurrence relation such that

$$T(0) = 0, T(1) = 1$$

$$T(n) = 7T(n-1) -12T(n-2)$$

And I'm trying to prove that $$T(n) = -3^n + 4^n$$

So far I have the following

Check base cases for 0,1

$$T(0) = -3^0 + 4^0 = 0$$
$$T(1) = -3^1 + 4^1 = 1$$

As both of these are true we can continue

Next we assume that (inductive hypothesis) $$T(n) = -3^n + 4^n$$

And for the inductive step we have $$T(n+1) = -3^{n+1} + 4^{n+1}$$

We know from our recurrence relation that $$T(n + 1) = 7T(n) - 12T(n-1)$$

This is where I am stuck. I know I can substitute in T(n) but I'm not sure what to do for T(n-1)

Comment: All you need to do is to show that $a_n=4^n-3^n$ satisfies the same recursion and initial conditions.

Comment: Your induction hypothesis should be that $T(k)=-3^{k}+4^k$ for **all** $k$ such that $0\le k\le n$, not just for $k=n$.

Comment: That's called [strong induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction); see the linked example of Fibonacci numbers, which have a similar recurrence relation

Answer (score 1):

"*Next we assume that $T(k)=-3^k+4^k$* for all $k\leq n$"

Now...

"*For the inductive step we* **want to prove that** $T(n+1)=-3^{n+1}+4^{n+1}$"

So to do that, we use a chain of equalities and algebra, and use the inductive hypothesis somewhere in the middle.

$$\begin{array}{rl}T(n+1)&=7T(n)-12T(n-1)\\&=\dots\\\vdots\\&=\dots~~\text{(by induction hypothesis)}\\ \vdots\\&=-3^{n+1}+4^{n+1}\end{array}$$

> $T(n+1)=7T(n)-12T(n-1)=7(-3^n+4^n)-12(-3^{n-1}+4^{n-1})=\dots$

Comment: I more or less understand this, however, I'm just wondering if there is a shorthand notation for writing the chain of equalities? I can see it will eventually reach 1 which is in our base cases and proved, therefore, we know it holds, but how would I write this out?

Comment: "*I can see it will eventually reach $1$*"  What?  In what way do you expect it to "reach 1"?  Are you suggesting that we just repeatedly replace $T(k)$ with $7T(k-1)-12T(k-2)$, doing $2n$ such replacements until you get a monsterous expression in terms of $T(1)$'s and $T(0)$'s?  Goodness no.  Just use algebraic manipulation of the expression resulting from replacing $T(n)$ and $T(n-1)$ with what our induction hypothesis says it should be equal to in terms of $3^k$'s and $4^k$'s

Comment: Well yes but this is what I was asking in the original question. I know that we 12(−3n−1+4n−1) for 12T(n-1), but I don't know what to do next to get −3^(n+1) + 4^(n+1)

Comment: algebraic manipulations... in particular remembering that $3^{n+1}=3\times 3^n = 9\times 3^{n-1}$ and that $a\times 3^n + b\times 3^n = (a+b)\times 3^n$.  Similarly for $4$ as the base.  Just combine like terms, factor, and distribute...

Answer (score 0):

Let P(m) denotes the truth value of the equation $T(m)=−3^m+4^m$
Assume $P(0)\wedge P(1)\land P(2)\wedge...\wedge P(k)$

We want to prove that P(K) is true, in other words, prove that $T(k+1)=−3^{k+1}+4^{k+1}$

By the recurrence relation we have \begin{align}
T(k+1)&=7T(k)−12T(k−1)\\
&=7(−3^k+4^k)-12(−3^{k-1}+4^{k-1})\\
&=(6+1)(−3^k+4^k)-4*3(−3^{k-1}+4^{k-1})\\
&=2*3(-3^k+4^k)+(−3^k+4^k)-4*(−3^{k}+3*4^{k-1})\\
&=2*(-3^{k+1}+3*4^k)−3^k+4^k+4*3^k-3*4^k\\
&=2*(-3^{k+1}+3*4^k)+3*3^k-2*4^k\\
&=2*(-3^{k+1})+2*(3*4^k)+3*3^k-2*4^k\\
&=2*(-3^{k+1})+3*3^k+6*4^k-2*4^k\\
&=-2*3^{k+1}+3^{k+1}+4*4^k\\
&=-3^{k+1}+4^{k+1}
\end{align}

This completes the proof.